# Removing duplicate NFTs

Tags: nft

I released an NFT collection with a few duplicate resources. After some time, the duplicate tokens were somehow marked, and began to look like this: https://explorer.solana.com/address/A83XKBPRq8Ezen89kt7NmhrTWcyFv3FCCFLUsPzCXU56

Can you please tell me if it is possible to return the normal appearance of tokens? (So that they return to the wallet).
Or how to make sure that duplicate NFTs are not deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to burn the duplicates. Here is how you can burn them in your phantom wallet:
https://help.phantom.app/hc/en-us/articles/8698835626003-How-to-burn-unwanted-Solana-based-NFTs-on-Phantom
And here the metaplex docs on how to do it programatically:
https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/burn-nfts

Comment: This is not about burning, but just the opposite, about NOT burning. Somehow the tokens ended up being marked as having the same resource. And this is exactly what is needed. BUT, someone, somehow, marks them as possibly fake. They disappear from the wallet, but they are visible in the Metaplex collection.
And I need to understand who spoils them in order to prevent this later.
Or perhaps there is some method whereby duplicates are not flagged in this way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've misunderstood the way that token standards should be implemented.

A master edition should never be duplicated. The issue you are facing will always be present if you attempt to create two identical master editions, for the reason described in the warning message - a duplicate master edition is typically a spoofed NFT that is used by scammers to steal funds.

It looks like the most appropriate standard in your case would be a `NonFungibleEdition`, which is a 'print' of a master edition NFT. You can create multiple prints from a single master edition without encountering this error.

You might also make use of the `FungibleAsset` standard, although this would more often be used to represent an in-game consumable (i.e. fuel), rather than something like a vehicle or mount.

You can read more about it here: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#print-a-new-edition-from-a-master-edition.